# protocol method not called in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have created protocol in swift use in objective c file but protocol method does not called here is code

@Swift file

```
@objc protocol clickBookmarksProtocolDelegate
{
 func openbook(bookmark : String)
}
var delegate : clickBookmarksProtocolDelegate?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  a = data[indexPath.row][main]
  println(a)
  if (a == "Bookmarks")
  {
     self.delegate?.openbook(data[indexPath.row][url])
     dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
  }
```

@obj C  .m file

```
#import "Video_Downloader-Swift.h"

@interface BrowserViewController() <clickBookmarksProtocolDelegate>

@end

- (void)openbook:(NSString * __nonnull)bookmark
{
 [self loadAddress:bookmark];
 _addressBar.text=bookmark;
}
```

Method does not call

Comment: Have you set the delegate somewhere ?

Comment: thnx to reply where i can set it???

Comment: no i have not set delegate

Comment: Well, it depends how your viewcontrollers interact with each other. But usually in BrowserViewController you have somewhere a reference to your other controller, there you can add `self.otherViewController.delegate = self;`

Comment: Are you presenting the Swift class in the BrowserViewController? Post your related code

Comment: How do you show the tableview ? how is it related to BrowserViewController ?

Comment: BrowseViewController is not a table view it's Web view

Comment: Yep, i'm asking how the other viewcontroller (the one that contains the tableview) is related to browserviewcontroller

Comment: When user click on any cell which contains url it's open in browserviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't use delegate for this. Delegates are used like some sort of a callback. For instance imagine you have a controller that will show another one:

`FirstViewController -> SecondViewController`

Delegates, are used in this case when your SecondViewController wants to call the FirstViewController.

In your case you just want to display SecondViewController, for this you have a few options.

The simplest if you have a navigation view controller is to push the new BrowserViewController in your didSelectCell method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(BrowserViewController(), animated: true)
}
```